# How load annotations.tsv file to Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: csv, annotations, google-custom-search

Trying to upload an annotations.tsv file to CSE, the upload dialogue says "File uploading is not successful". That's all. There's no specific error and no apparent cause. Everything looks fine.

The file is called: `annotations.tsv`

It has headers on the first line: `URL<tab>Label<tab>Score`

The file includes lines of the form: `*somedomain.com/*<tab>_cse_etc<tab>1`

And: `someotherdomain/*<tab>_cse_etc<1>`

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: What is "<1>" in your example? it should be "<tab>score", no? I was seeing the same error and it was a problem with the format of my file. The error message from Google is somewhat confusing. It was not error with uploading, but file format.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out my error in transcribing the problem!

Comment: I think there is an issue with your tsv file. Can you share a link to your file (pastebin for example)?

Comment: thx for looking into it, jira. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the url patterns was invalid.

Google CSE does not give explicit error messages. If the file's list of patterns contains any that are invalid, it just rejects the whole file. If there are any other problems with the file, it just rejects the whole file.

The invalid pattern was of the form `*.domainName.*`

Whereas these are valid patterns:

```
www.domainName.com/    
www.domainName.com/*
subdomainName.domainName.com/dirName/*
*.domainName.com/*
```

This is not valid: `*.domainName.*`

Comment: It's worth noting that Google CSE feedback folk were very helpful in trying to find the root of the problem. Might save us all a lot of time and trouble if they simply had meaningful error messages.